# Angular 2 undefined property this.logbooks

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular 2 and I'm making an application myself. I'm using the InMemoryWebApiModule to mock an API. I'm learning from the "Tour of heroes" tutorial on the angular website. Although my code appears the same to me it doesn't work as it's supposed.

Somehow this.logbooks isn't being set. What am I missing?

//in-memory-data.service.ts

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        let user = {"id":9,"username":"admin"};
        let logbooks = [
            {"id":1,"name":"1Naam"},
            {"id":2,"name":"2Naam"}
        ];
        return {user,logbooks};
    }
}
```

//logbooks.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LogbookService} from './logbook.service';
import {Logbook} from "./logbook";

@Component({
    selector: 'logbooks',
    template: `
        <h2>Your logbooks</h2>
        <ul *ngFor="let logbook of logbooks" class="logbooks">
            <li>Name: {{ logbook.name }}</li>
        </ul>

        `,
    providers: [LogbookService]
})

export class LogbooksComponent implements OnInit {
    logbooks: Logbook[]

    constructor(private logbookService: LogbookService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('in Lifecycle hook! Yeah!');
        this.getLogbooks();
        console.log("Den logbooks" + this.logbooks[1].name);
    }

    getLogbooks(): void {
        this.logbookService.getLogbooks().then(logbooks => this.logbooks = logbooks);
    }
}
```

//logbook.service.ts

```
import {Logbook} from "./logbook";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class LogbookService {
    getLogbooks() : Promise<Logbook[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.logbooksrUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Logbook[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private logbooksrUrl = 'app/logbooks';  // URL to web api

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**the output in developer console**

```
[WDS] Disconnected!  main.bundle.js:44082:10
in Lifecycle hook! Yeah!  main.bundle.js:55753:9
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:6:0 caused by: this.logbooks is undefined  main.bundle.js:36969:9
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: this.logbooks is undefined  main.bundle.js:36971:13
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:  main.bundle.js:36974:13
LogbooksComponent</LogbooksComponent.prototype.ngOnInit@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:55755:9
anonymous/Wrapper_LogbooksComponent.prototype.ngDoCheck@/AppModule/LogbooksComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:20:40
anonymous/View_AppComponent0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:86:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52693:9
DebugAppView</DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52786:13
anonymous/View_AppComponent_Host0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:27:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52693:9
DebugAppView</DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52786:13
ViewRef_</ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:37861:9
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23642:75
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23642:13
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype._loadComponent@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23620:9
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.bootstrap@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23611:9
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23513:82
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23513:13
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone/</</<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23481:21
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64628:17
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:25787:28
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64627:17
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64510:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64898:52
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64661:21
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:25778:28
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64660:21
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64550:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64797:25
  main.bundle.js:36975:13
ERROR CONTEXT:  main.bundle.js:36978:13
Object { _view: Object, _nodeIndex: 8, _tplRow: 6, _tplCol: 0 }  main.bundle.js:36979:13
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:6:0 caused by: this.logbooks is undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Object { _nativeError: Error, originalError: TypeError, context: Object, stack: "" } LogbooksComponent</LogbooksComponent.prototype.ngOnInit@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:55755:9
anonymous/Wrapper_LogbooksComponent.prototype.ngDoCheck@/AppModule/LogbooksComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:20:40
anonymous/View_AppComponent0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:86:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52693:9
DebugAppView</DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52786:13
anonymous/View_AppComponent_Host0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:27:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52693:9
DebugAppView</DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52786:13
ViewRef_</ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:37861:9
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23642:75
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23642:13
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype._loadComponent@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23620:9
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.bootstrap@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23611:9
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23513:82
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23513:13
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone/</</<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23481:21
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64628:17
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:25787:28
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64627:17
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64510:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64898:52
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64661:21
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:25778:28
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64660:21
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64550:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64797:25
  main.bundle.js:64784:13
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:6:0 caused by: this.logbooks is undefined
LogbooksComponent</LogbooksComponent.prototype.ngOnInit@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:55755:9
anonymous/Wrapper_LogbooksComponent.prototype.ngDoCheck@/AppModule/LogbooksComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:20:40
anonymous/View_AppComponent0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:86:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52693:9
DebugAppView</DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52786:13
anonymous/View_AppComponent_Host0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:27:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52693:9
DebugAppView</DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52786:13
ViewRef_</ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:37861:9
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23642:75
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23642:13
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype._loadComponent@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23620:9
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.bootstrap@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23611:9
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23513:82
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23513:13
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone/</</<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:23481:21
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64628:17
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:25787:28
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64627:17
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64510:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64898:52
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64661:21
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:25778:28
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64660:21
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64550:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64797:25

Stack trace:
resolvePromise@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64864:31
makeResolver/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64841:13
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64628:17
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64510:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64898:52
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64661:21
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64550:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64797:25
  main.bundle.js:64786:9
```

Somehow the this.logbooks isn't being set properly after component initialisation. What am I missing? How to fix.

I've been messing with this for over a day so help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

MackDoms

edit:

//logbook.ts

```
export class Logbook {
    public name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is the tutorial I'm referring to, if you look at heroes.component.ts you can see they don't initialise the array as well:

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```
this.getLogbooks();
```

is an async operation

```
console.log("Den logbooks" + this.logbooks[1].name);
```

right under it will give an undefined error.

if you want to use `this.logbooks`' value by the time it arrived you should move your logic to the promises callback which is the `then` part of this function.

```
getLogbooks(): void {
        this.logbookService.getLogbooks().then(logbooks => this.logbooks = logbooks);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works! Amazing how 'stupid' I can be.. :-)

Comment: @MackDoms We've all been there :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay!

Comment: @MackDoms haha, no problem :-)